# Javascript if statement doesn't read condition

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, frontend

I have a div that should toggle dark mode on or off whenever it is clicked based on the number of times it has been clicked. However this code doesn't seem to work. The click count functions fine, it's just the if statement that is giving me issues.

```
let x = 0;
document.getElementById("darkmode").onmousedown = function darkMode(){
    x+=1;
    console.log(x);
 }
if(x % 2 == 0){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0A0A0A";
} 
else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

The colour of the background does not change at all. I tried using a simpler condition, (x == 5), in the if statement but that didn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're only checking the conditional on page load, not on button click. Move the conditionals directly under `console.log(x);` and it'll work.

Comment: That `if` statement only runs once, when the javascript loads. There's nothing telling the browser to change the background every time to the `onmousedown` event is fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking the conditional on page load, not on button click. Move the conditionals inside of the event listener. Additionally, if the default page load is NOT darkmode, then set `let x = 1;` to start so the first click toggles darkmode on.

Though as `x` is just toggling between 2 values, it should probably be a boolean instead - `let darkmode = false;` and instead of `x++` you'd do `darkMode = !darkMode;`

```js
let darkmode = false;
document.getElementById("darkmode").onmousedown = function darkMode(event) {
  darkmode = !darkmode;
  
  // move the conditional logic inside of the event function
  if(darkmode){
    document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.darkmode {
  background-color: #0A0A0A;
}

.darkmode p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="darkmode">Toggle darkmode</a>
<p>here is some content</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I've just started learning JS after coming from C++ and I had no idea that conditionals only ran once on page load. Thanks for the boolean tip as well, but I was planning on adding more themes.

Comment: It's not that _conditionals_ only run once on page load, it's that the entire script only runs once. i.e. `x` only gets initialized once, the `onmousedown` event listener only gets assigned once, etc. But once you put the code in the `onmousedown` event function, it gets run each time the `mousedown` event is triggered.

Comment: @ZuhayrElias You likely want to change this to a `click` listener instead, because if I mouse down on the link, then move my mouse and mouse up, the JS will currently still count that as "clicked" even though most UIs only consider it a click if the mouse down and mouse up event are on the same element. Also, a `click` is keyboard accessible too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event for more info.